# How to install ngx-bootstrap v7.0.0 for Angular 11?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-bootstrap 5.x.x in my Angular 8 project but now I have migrated my Angular v8 to v11 and I start facing issues with dropdown. It does not open on first click. I find they are recommended to use v7.0.0 but when I install it using

```
npm i ngx-bootstrap@7.0.0 --save
```

It throws an error

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for ngx-bootstrap@7.0.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Any help would be appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 7.0.0 is a Release candidate version, you should mention -rc and version. it becomes `npm i ngx-bootstrap@7.0.0-rc.1`
you can see install command from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap/v/7.0.0-rc.1).

it is ready to go out, but it isn't proven yet so it's not ready to be marked as a stable release quite yet. You can think of it as a mature beta release. for more details, you can visit [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle)

Comment: Thanks! It works but unfortunately my issue does not resolved !!!

Comment: If it works then your package should update, ultimately your issue should be resolved. What is the error message now? is it something related to version compatibility? or something else

Comment: I got it now. It was due to applying two conditional classes on same FontAwesome element and when 2nd becomes active then ngx-bootstrap does not append class on it. It looks wired but Yes. And when I removed 2nd class then it start working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the official npm CDN [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap) where the latest version is 6.2.0. As there is no 7.0 version available with the npm CDN that explains the problem. If you want to force install the version which is not yet published and in the queue then use

> npm i ngx-bootstrap@7.0.0-rc.1

Answer (score 0):

simply you can visit this for more information

[www.npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap/v/7.0.0-rc.1)